# How to pass variables to qmake project file when qmake is run

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I need to dynamically change my e.g. application name and subsequent defines when calling `qmake` on my project file.

An **example** would be:

```
include(version.pri)

QT       += core gui network concurrent

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
FLAVOR = ?

TARGET = ../bin/$$FLAVOR
TEMPLATE = app

message("Application name: $$APP_NAME")

!defined(APP_NAME) {
    APP_NAME = $$FLAVOR
}

!defined(APP_ORG) {
    APP_ORG = myorg
}

//...

message("Application name 2: $$APP_NAME")
```

**Output**

```
Application name:
Application name 2: ?
```

Above is an extract from my project file.

---

**Documentation:**

According to Qmake [documenation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#defined-name-type), I should be able to do the following:

```
FLAVOR = xyz

!defined(APP_NAME) {
    APP_NAME = $$FLAVOR
}
```

*Purpose of above code:*

*Check if APP_NAME is defined (anywhere, even passed as `qmake` parameter). If it is NOT defined, then set `APP_NAME` equal to `FLAVOR` which contains xyz*

**I have tried:**

- `qmake -config debug "DEFINES += APP_NAME = myappname"`
- `qmake -config debug "APP_NAME = myappname"`
- `qmake -config debug APP_NAME = myappname`

of which none work.

**How can I pass a definition to qmake which will set a variable in the Makefile i.e. `APP_NAME` as shown in the above example?**

**please note**: *some answers suggest of an issue with the question title. I have since edited the title to a more appropriate summary of my question and what I hope to achieve*

Comment: According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html, the second one *should* work - except the example they show has no spaces.  Have you tried `qmake -config debug "APP_NAME=myappname"`?

Comment: Also, what platform are you running on?

Comment: @MartinBonner I think I did try it. Also, running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with QMAKE 3 and Qt 5.5.1

Comment: @talamaki even though the question title may suggest a duplicate, my question with the related understanding would disagree. Also, O was looking for something similar to `qmake ... foo=bar` where foo is used in the `.pro` file and this duplicate does not provide such an example

Comment: Ok, you have the dynamic aspect in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are not trying to add DEFINES (as in preprocessor defines, passed to the compiler), but to "assign" variables for use inside the QMake project file.

The following works for me:

```
QT       += core gui network concurrent

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
FLAVOR = ?

TARGET = ../bin/$$FLAVOR
TEMPLATE = app

message("Application name: $$APP_NAME")

!defined(APP_NAME, var) {
    APP_NAME = $$FLAVOR
}

message("Application name 2: $$APP_NAME")
```

One seemingly crucial change to make the "defined"-statement work was to add "var" as a second parameter, as you can see. Not sure why, but without it, the second output was "?", while the first one was correctly "myappname".

The output of qmake being:

```
...\Desktop\test_qmake>qmake -config debug "APP_NAME = myappname"
Project MESSAGE: Application name: myappname
Project MESSAGE: Application name 2: myappname
Project MESSAGE: Application name: myappname
Project MESSAGE: Application name 2: myappname
Project MESSAGE: Application name: myappname
Project MESSAGE: Application name 2: myappname

...\Desktop\test_qmake>qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.7.1 in C:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/lib
```

// EDIT: Regarding the "defined"-statement, the docs say "[...] If type is omitted, checks all functions.", where "type" is the second parameter. Seems to be taken literally, i.e. only functions are checked, but no variables.
[QMake function reference "defined"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#defined-name-type)

Comment: Thank you for the indepth explanation and suggestion!

Comment: Works as expected!

Comment: @KGCybeX Glad to help. Now that it's pretty clear you do **not** need "preprocessor defines", the question's title is very misleading. If I'm not completely wrong, you only wanted to know how to assign variables for QMake project files by command line arguments. At least that's what my answer was about.

Comment: @user2277520 and that is exactly what I wanted but phrased it incorrectly. I have since edited the question title to make it more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass defines to qmake like this:

```
qmake DEFINES+="APP_NAME myappname"
```

And if you want to add defines in a pro file you do like this:

```
DEFINES += "APP_NAME=myappname"
```

Comment: `/home/cybex/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake -config debug DEFINES+="APP_NAME myappname" ` produces the same output as mentioned in question

Comment: @KGCybeX You are asking about how to set defines in Makefile and you are testing output of .pro files??? If you need to set values into .pro files use qmake -project instead of qmake -config Answer from talamaki makes exactly what you have asked in your question

Comment: Adding ` DEFINES += "APP_NAME=myappname" ` to the top of the project file also does not work. Neither does this, "APP_NAME=myappname" or "APP_NAME = myappname". Strangely APP_NAME = myappname assigns the value initially as expected, but after `defined ` evaluation, it outputs `?`

Comment: @KGCybeX DEFINES in qmake/.pro files is about pre-processor defines to be put in the generated Makefile. Your question title (Add DEFINES to qmake project file when compiling makefile) is obviously misleading. The answer by user2277520 is obviously what you are looking for.

Comment: Allow me to edit the question title to better suite the question. And thank you for the explanation, it may have taken me a while to figure it out.

Comment: @talamaki: would you say the question title is appropriate to and summarizes that which I am asking?

Comment: I changed the title to match the question better.

Comment: Just note that when the variable is added like in user2277520's answer it doesn't end up to the Makefile and preprocessor but is only for qmake, but that's actually what you need.